# how to find possible numbers which can fit a row and column of sudoku board on python?

Tags: python

I have to Find the possible numbers that can fit in a cell whose row and column indexes are Given.

the board is as follows

```
board = [['4', '.', '7', '.', '.', '8', '9', '6', '2'],
         ['.', '.', '1', '.', '2', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['5', '.', '.', '7', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['7', '5', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '4'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '4', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['6', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '9', '8'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '1', '.', '.', '6'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '5', '.', '8', '.', '.'],
         ['1', '2', '9', '4', '.', '.', '3', '.', '5']
         ]
```

now it should get possible numbers which an fit in a row and coulmn

for example:

```
def get_possible_numbers(board,row,col)

get_possible_numbers(board,0,0)
```

which should return the following:

```
['4']
```

Comment: You should start by looking at each 3x3 grid and figuring it out from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
board = [['4', '.', '7', '.', '.', '8', '9', '6', '2'],
         ['.', '.', '1', '.', '2', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['5', '.', '.', '7', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['7', '5', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '4'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '4', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['6', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '9', '8'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '1', '.', '.', '6'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '5', '.', '8', '.', '.'],
         ['1', '2', '9', '4', '.', '.', '3', '.', '5']
         ]

def get_possible_numbers(board,row,col):
    possible_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9]
    if board[row][col] != ".":
        return [board[row][col]]
    else:
        for i in range(9):
            if board[row][i]!=".":
                if int(board[row][i]) in possible_numbers:
                    possible_numbers.remove(int(board[row][i]))
            if board[i][col]!=".":
                if int(board[i][col]) in possible_numbers:
                    possible_numbers.remove(int(board[i][col]))
        return possible_numbers

print (get_possible_numbers(board, 3, 3))
```

It is probably not the shortest solution but it is self explanatory.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work out for get_possible_numbers(board,3,3)

Comment: Actually its zero bases indexing, so (3, 3) would be read as 4th row, 4th column, so now if you examine then the output is `[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]`, because in the corresponding rows and columns we have `[7, 5, 4]`, which are excluded in the output, isn't this what you expected ?, For clearance the 4th row here is : `['7', '5', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '4']`

Comment: ya but it shows some error saying the following
get_possible_numbers(board,3,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 22, in get_possible_numbers
builtins.AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: See if the new one works? BTW the previous version was working fine on my machine.

Comment: it doesnt work yet.. it works for numbers like get_possible_numbers(board,0,0)

Comment: but for others shows same error

Comment: Are you using python 3 or python 2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76718/discussion-between-zeeran-and-anmol-uppal).

Comment: Edited and working in case of Python 3